# SHOW CRATE TABLE in Netezza Aginity

Tags: sql, netezza

What is the equivalent command `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` from MySQL in Netezza SQL.

For example I have the iris table with these columns.

[image]

**My Expected output**

Add screenshot using MySQL with HeidiSQL ID

[image]

I need a statement equivalent to `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`, from
[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html).

Comment: "*I need to see how the table was created*" Like, how it was created initially? Or are you just looking for the DDL of a table as it currently exists?

Comment: db2 has `describe` if I'm not mistaken , not sure if netteza has he same command or not , give ita shot.

Comment: @esqew I already edited the question to better explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

On Netezza, there is no simple way to get the ddl of a table by, for example, running a query on a system view.

Alternative: On the Netezza host, if you have access, you could use the command line tool nz_ddl_table (`/nz/support/bin/nz_ddl_table`). This is a complex script that uses a lot of system views (like `_v_relation_column`) to construct the DDL.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to operate general syntax:

```
CREATE [ TEMPORARY | TEMP ] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] <table>
( <col> <type> [<col_constraint>][,<col> <type> [<col_constraint>]…]
[<table_constraint>[,<table_constraint>… ] )
[ DISTRIBUTE ON { RANDOM | [HASH] (<col>[,<col>…]) } ]
[ ORGANIZE ON { (<col>) | NONE } ]
[ ROW SECURITY ]
```

You can have more references from IBM website below!

[IBM Netezza SQL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=reference-create-table)

Comment: The OP is asking how to programmatically generate such a query based on a pre-existing table. This does not answer the question.